# ag-grid - Column not selected by default in the columns tool panel in pivot mode when headerName is different than field

Tags: ag-grid

I am using `ag-grid-enterprise.js` version 24.0.0, and this problem also exists in version 23.0.0. If the `columnDefs` `headerName` is different than the `field`, then the column is not selected by default in the ag-grid Columns Tool Panel. Is there a way around this?

Here is my configuration:

```
gridOptions = {
   columnDefs: [
      enablePivot: true,
      enableRowGroup: true,
      field: 'retail_env',
      headerName: 'Retail Environment'
   ],
   sideBar: true,
   pivotMode: true,
   pivotPanelShow: 'always'
}
```

When headerName is the same as field, the column IS selected properly in the columns tool panel.

This looks like a bug in ag-grid, but I can't tell for sure.

I would appreciate any help you might have!

Comment: can you provide sample code to reproduce this? also make sure defaultColDef doesn't have hide property set to true

Answer (score 0):

While trying to create the sample code to recreate the problem (Thanks, @sandeep joshi!), I found the problem in my application. There is no problem with ag-grid in this area.

The problem was that I was not calling `setRowGroupColumns()` with the `headerName`'s instead of the `field`'s. The correct code is:

```
gridOptions.columnApi.setRowGroupColumns(['retail_env'])
```